# How to select a number of files in a menu and pass that to a submenu using ksh/bash

Tags: bash, ksh

List number of files in a menu.

The main goal is to select an option from a list of files in a menu and then use that selected option in a submenu. The script that works for  me is where the main menu options are constant. It doesn't work when the  options variable is *.dbf. Instead we get Invalid option.

The following code doesn't work for me.

```
# function dbasubmenu 
dbasubmenu () {
  options=("DB reorg" "DB index" "DB TableCreation" "DB Submenu quit")
  prompt="Pick a Submenu option: "
  local PS3="$prompt"

  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
      case $opt in
          "DB reorg")
              echo "You picked $opt in DB reorg menu for $dbfile"
              ;;
          "DB index")
              echo "you picked $opt in DB index menu for $dbfile"
              ;;
           "DB TableCreation")
             echo "you picked $opt in DB TableCreation menu for $dbfile"
             ;;
          "DB Submenu quit")
              echo "exiting now the DB Submenu"
              return
              ;;
          *) echo "Invalid option $REPLY. Try a valid option ";continue;;
      esac
  done
}


#Main menu
  prompt="Pick a DB Main menu option: "
  PS3="$prompt"

  dbfs=(*.dbf)
   select dbfile in "${dbfs[@]%.dbf}"
    do 
       case $dbfile in
            "DB Mainmenu")
             echo "you picked $dbfile in DB Main menu "
             ;;
             "DB Submenu")
              dbasubmenu $dbfile
             ;;
              "DB Mainmenu quit")
                echo 
                echo "We're all done with the processing !!!!"
                exit
                ;;
            *) echo "Invalid option $REPLY. Try a valid option ";continue;;
          esac

      done
```

We've several dbf files in different db directories. As an example, a.dbf
    b.dbf c.dbf d.dbf. We need all the 4 files to be displayed in the main
    menu,  select any one of the above dbf files and use that dbf file to
    be used in a   sub menu. when the job is completed, we need to exit
    out of the sub menu and   return back to the main menu to select another
    dbf file for processing.

The error message we're getting now is *Invalid Option*.

Comment: In the main menu code after the `select/do`, and before the `case ...`, add a `echo "${dbfile}`' to see what's in `$dbfile` to understand why you don't get a match with your `case` statement options; perhaps I don't understand the question but I don't see how you can strip the '.dbf' off of you filenames, and expect any of the resulting items ('a','b','c','d') to match the strings ('DB Mainmenu', 'DB Submenu', 'DB Mainmenu quit') ??

Comment: So you want to run the main `select` inside of a loop? Then maybe include an option on the menu for `finished processing`? Good luck.

Comment: it would probably help if you provided a small example of the files in question and what you expect the entire main menu to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseline:

- without an example of what the main menu is supposed to look like, and ...
- taking into consideration that the first 2 main menu options reference a specific `$dbfile`, and ...
- maintaining the OP's current output design and ...
- making no changes to the `dbasubmenu()` function and ...
- the question is tagged with both `bash` and `ksh`, so I'm going to pick `bash` and ...
- using files `a.dbf b.dbf c.dbf` for demo purposes ...

I'm going to assume that the main menu should look something like:

```
1) DB Mainmenu - a
2) DB Mainmenu - b
3) DB Mainmenu - c
4) DB Submenu - a
5) DB Submenu - b
6) DB Submenu - c
7) DB Mainmenu quit
Pick a DB Main menu option:
```

The main menu block of code now looks like:

```
prompt="Pick a DB Main menu option: "
PS3="$prompt"

# save current COLUMNS sexttting; redefined as relatively narrow to force
# 'select' to display menu list as single column

oldCOLUMNS=${COLUMNS}
COLUMNS=8

dbfs=(*.dbf)                    # load *.dbf file list into array
dbfsmenu=( ${dbfs[@]%.dbf} )    # strip '.dbf' from file names and put in new array;
                                # used solely for menu/display purposes

# add menu prefixes to our dbfsmenu array items, add the 'quit' option on the end

select opt in "${dbfsmenu[@]/#/DB Mainmenu - }" "${dbfsmenu[@]/#/DB Submenu - }" "DB Mainmenu quit"
do
    # process our selected option; for the options where we want $dbfile
    # we'll need to strip off the menu prefix and add the '.dbf' suffix

    dbfile="${opt##* }.dbf"

    case $opt in
        # need to list 'quit' item first to keep from matching
        # wildcard pattern for 'DB Mainmenu*'

        "DB Mainmenu quit")  echo
                             echo "We're all done with the processing !!!!"
                             exit                                           ;;

        "DB Mainmenu"*)      echo "You picked ${dbfile} in DB Main Menue"   ;;

        "DB Submenu"*)       dbasubmenu ${dbfile}                           ;;

        *)                   echo "Invalid option. Try a valid option "
                             continue                                       ;;
    esac
done

# reset COLUMNS to what it was

COLUMNS=${oldCOLUMNS}
```

Let's take it for a test run:

```
1) DB Mainmenu - a
2) DB Mainmenu - b
3) DB Mainmenu - c
4) DB Submenu - a
5) DB Submenu - b
6) DB Submenu - c
7) DB Mainmenu quit
Pick a DB Main menu option: 1
You picked a.dbf in DB Main Menue
Pick a DB Main menu option: 2
You picked b.dbf in DB Main Menue
Pick a DB Main menu option: 3
You picked c.dbf in DB Main Menue
Pick a DB Main menu option: 4
1) DB reorg
2) DB index
3) DB TableCreation
4) DB Submenu quit
Pick a Submenu option: 1
You picked DB reorg in DB reorg menu for a.dbf
Pick a Submenu option: 2
you picked DB index in DB index menu for a.dbf
Pick a Submenu option: 3
you picked DB TableCreation in DB TableCreation menu for a.dbf
Pick a Submenu option: 4
exiting now the DB Submenu
Pick a DB Main menu option: 7

We're all done with the processing !!!!
```

Formatting could be cleaned up a bit to make it easier to read, and it may be desirable to redisplay the menus for follow-on picks ... I'll leave that up to the OP ...

Comment: Thanks Mark for the quick response. Your answer was perfect. On another note, after going through the sub menu process and returning back to the main menu to pick another option, is there a way to print the main menu again.

Comment: 1) DB Mainmenu - a
2) DB Mainmenu - b
3) DB Mainmenu - c
4) DB Submenu - a
5) DB Submenu - b
6) DB Submenu - c
7) DB Mainmenu quit  OR print the menu horizontally instead of vertically? Please advise

Comment: re: `print menu horizontally` - that's where COLUMNS comes into play; by setting to a value (8) I know is less than any of the menu option string lengths, `select`is forced to limit the output to one item per line; so, for a horizontal display of the menu you would want to set COLUMNS to something bigger than the combined lengths of all the menu options; in this example each of the 7 menu items is 17-19 characters in length so you could try setting COLUMNS to something greater than 7x19 = 133 (keep in mind my file names are single-character lengths so you'll likely need to go a bit bigger)

Comment: try changing the value of COLUMNS and see how it affects the width of your menu display

Comment: re: `reprinting the menu` - some documentation says the menu should auto-reprint on the next time through the loop (it obviously doesn't in my example which may be an issue with the cygwin/bash implementation I wrote that in); what you could always do is end **each** case option with a 'break', then wrap the `select/do` loop in an outer `while true/d`o loop (then you'd need a way to pass the 'quit' choice out to the outer loop effectively issuing a break+break)

Comment: If you want the main menu to print again, you just need to hit the return key w/o picking an option. This was an accidental finding. :)

Comment: @Aires69 thanks for the heads up; I verified this works in my cygwin/bash env, too

Comment: Executing this script in ksh, get this error ./menu_submenu.ksh[46]: "${dbfsmenu[@]/#/DB Mainmenu - }": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: ahhh, yeah, I wrote that in `bash` (one of the tags you assigned to your question); I'm not sure if there's an equivalent in `ksh`

Comment: not much changes to be done in ksh. They're as follows: 1) dbfs=$(ls *.dbf) 2) set -A dbfsmenu $(echo $dbfs) 3) select opt in "${dbfsmenu[@]}" "DBSubmenu" "DBMainmenuQuit"   # cannot have DBMainmenu Quit, in ksh it should be as one word. 4) dbfile="${opt##* }" 5) ${dbfsmenu[$REPLY-1]})    echo ${dbfile} > x
                                  echo "You picked ${dbfile} in DB Main Menue" ;;